# Quiero que aparezca la edad si es mayor pero no me sale :c aqui mis codigos

Tags: php

HTML:
[image: html]

Php[image: pHP]

ERROR :(

[image: ayudaaaa!!! :(]

Quiero que aparezca si es mayor de edad y si no que lo diga pero no me daja a la hora de poner la edad me sale error

Comment: Tu código como texto por favor

Answer (score 0):

Estas enviando las variables mediante POST y las estas recibiendo mediante GET, proba recibirlos mediante POST osea

```
$_POST['nombre'] 
$_POST['edad']
```

Comment: Tienes problemas con tus comillas